# Hibernate Kotlin difference between @Column and @get:Column?

Tags: hibernate, kotlin

What is the difference between @get:Column and @Column in Hibernate Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

`@get:Column` applies the annotation to the property's getter method, while `@Column` ends up annotating the underlying field. In Hibernate, both of those will have roughly the same effect, although there might be [some small differences](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/258541).

---

The `get:` prefix in `@get:Column` is a [**use-site target**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets). It's useful when one thing in Kotlin corresponds to multiple things in Java. The use-site target selects which of the Java things the annotation should apply to.

For example, a Kotlin `val` property can be represented as a field with a getter method in Java. The `@Column` annotation can apply to both a field and a method, so applying that annotation to a Kotlin property is in a sense ambiguous when viewed from Java. It could apply either to the underlying field or to the getter method.

Using `@get:Column` specifies that the annotation should apply specifically to the property's getter method, rather than to the field. Omitting the use-site target means Kotlin will try to pick one for you. From the two targets that the `Column` annotation can have, Kotlin will pick `field` by default. You could also specify `@field:Column` if you want to specifically target the field.

Comment: Thank's for the detailed answer! But if so, then what sense would it make , for instance, to have both '@get:Column' and '@get:ManyToOne' on the same field?